# Index Match within an index match? or Index matching from two different sheets - Excel formula

Tags: excel, formula, vlookup, index-match

I am using an index match in the main sheet 1 to find one set of values pulling from sheet 2 but is it possible to search in sheet 3 if the value results in #NA? or is there another formula statement to begin with instead?

Formula:
INDEX(Sheet_2!C:C,MATCH('Sheet_1'!B2, Sheet_2!B:B,0))

Not sure of its helpful but matching on orderids and indexing the varying company's names.

Thank you,
Jmar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap in IFERROR()

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet_2!C:C,MATCH('Sheet_1'!B2, Sheet_2!B:B,0)),INDEX(Sheet_3!C:C,MATCH('Sheet_1'!B2, Sheet_3!B:B,0)))
```

Now it will search the third tab if the second tab return an error.

Comment: iferror! Learned another great example of how to use this. Thank you Scott!

Comment: just marked - It worked :)